# Question about volume integral related to vector field.

Tags: calculus

So I've been sent these 2 questions to solve, but frankly, I keep messing up the boundaries and therefore the value of the triple integral that is given.

Question $(a)$ is quite difficult to solve for that very reason. 
Question$(b)$ is a bit vague to me, and I would like someone to explain what is meant at that question, and, of course to give the right solution with respect to the situation described in the overall question.

The question is listed below:
[image]

Comment: Note that the boundary of $D$ is $S_5 \cup S_7$. So, the divergence theorem tells us to calculate the flux integrals across $S_5$ and $S_7$, and add them (with correct sign). Do you think you can figure out the correct signs?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I could really use a detailed solution to know which steps to take.

Comment: I've posted a solution below. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $D = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | 25 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 49\}$, then $\partial D = S_5 \cup S_7$. Using the divergence theorem, we know that, $$\iiint_D \nabla \cdot \textbf{F} dV = \iint_{\partial D} \textbf{F} \cdot d\textbf{S}$$ So, we can split this up to the flux integral over $S_5$ and the flux integral over $S_7$ which equal $5a+b$ and $7a+b$ respectively. Now, I need to add these together keeping in mind the orientation. Let's work out the orientation intuitively. The flux integral corresponds to the outward pointing normal. If I'm in the annular region D, the divergence tells me my flow outwards. So a positive divergence relates to a flow out of $S_7$ in the direction of its outward pointing normal, and a flow into $S_5$ opposite to the direction of its outward pointing normal. So, we give the flux integral over $S_5$ the negative sign. Our answer is then $$(7a+b) - (5a+b) = 2a$$

For part b, note that if $\textbf{F} = \nabla \times \textbf{G}$, then $\textbf{F}$ is the curl of some field. What do you know about $\nabla \cdot \textbf{F} = \nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \textbf{G})$, and what does that imply for the integral?